# Weird error while using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I was following [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html#define-the-data-you-want-to-scrape) tutorial for learning scrapy but I am having a very weird issue. It extracts the url `start_urls` and places it in `data.json`. Here is the code I used:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ArticleItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()

class ScholarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scholar"
    allowed_domains = ["mininova.org/"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.mininova.org/today']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/tor/13278067'], deny=['http://www.mininova.org/today']), 'parse')]

def parse(self, response):
    article = ArticleItem()
    article['url'] = response.url
    return article
```

For development purpose, I have tried extracting only urls and that too a very specific url that ends with `/tor/13278067`. I ran the spider in following manner:

```
$ scrapy crawl scholar -o data.json
```

And the content in `data.json` I found was this:

```
[{"url": "http://www.mininova.org/today"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `rules`, you need to inherit from `CrawlSpider` instead of `Spider`. But when inheriting from `CrawlSpider`, you must not override the `parse()` method, but use a different name for your callback. So basically, this is what you need:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ArticleItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()

# inherit from CrawlSpider instead of Spider
class ScholarSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "scholar"
    allowed_domains = ["mininova.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.mininova.org/today']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/tor/\d+']), callback='parse_url')]

    # do not use parse() because CrawlSpider
    # needs it for his normal operation
    def parse_url(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['url'] = response.url
        return article
```

Comment: Oh okay. In my case, the `CrawlSpider` was not present in the scrapy module. I changed `13278067` to `\d+`, it scrapes only the first result. Do you know why? Also there is no output to the json file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated my answer, CrawlSpider is under `scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider`.

Comment: As for the `\d+`, it will work. I updated my answer to reflect this. Run it as `scrapy crawl scholar -o data.jl`.

Comment: No, this is not the reason it worked. It would work even if you don't explicitly specify `callback='parse_url'`, you could just write `'parse_url'`, because the second argument for the `Rule` constructor is `callback`, and this is the second argument so we are good. I just like to do it explicitly as a good habit, thats all.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was wondering. But I compared your code and my code(after editing), and I found them same. Still your worked and mine didn't. I rewrote the code and then it did work. Still wondering why did it work.

Comment: Did you check the indentation? Maybe the function `parse_url` was not under the class, but rather had the wrong indentation and was global? Like in your original question, it is not a member of your class, which is wrong. You should indent it further.